# CHMOD Folder + subfolder + subfolder etc

Tags: permissions

I've been overlooking this problem for several hours and I'm starting to get crazy. I have a few folders sharing with users. When setting up the permissions the folders are being displayed ok, but can't acces the subfolders (or see the content).

What I've been trying:

```
chmod -R 770 test
```

As I said, I can acces the content of the folder test, but can't acces test > test 1 > test 2 >. How do I apply these settings to all enclosed folders and files?

Kind regards,

[EDIT]
When doing chmod -R 770 test I get the following output:

```
drwxrwx--- 3 server server 4069 jan 20 17:25 test1
```

Comment: You need execute permissions (which you are setting to 0) in order to list the contents of a folder. (See, eg, http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/filepermissions.htm )

Comment: Thanks chronitis, but how do I change settings to following: Owner and usergroup can Read, write, execute, and others can't do anything?

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l test` and `ls -ld test`.

Comment: Hi Falconer,

Out put is:
drw-rw-r-- server server 4069 jan 20 15:38 test

Comment: @rwzdoorn And did you ran the `chmod` command already? Because it says that the test folder is still readable by others. Your username is `server`? Or you run the command with sudo?

Comment: @falconer I did ran chmod, changed it to 777 and it applied only for 1 folder. My username is server. I didn't use SUDO. Problem is I tried to use 770 but it's not applying to all folders in the folder.

Comment: @falconer editted!

Comment: @rwzdoorn That looks correct. The subdirectory was set to 770 as you wanted. So you say with those permissions you can't get into the `test1` directory with the `server` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, problem solved:

Just a small thing, never use the GUI users and groups option, just use your terminal.

What I did (and works):

```
sudo -s
[your root password]
```

Create a group and add users:

```
sudo groupadd [groupname] * creates a group
sudo usermod -a -G [groupname] [username] *add the user to the group
```

Make a folder executable for a group and give rights:

```
sudo chgrp -R [groupname] [path/to/folder] * Gives usergroup also access
sudo chmod -R 770 [path/to/folder] * Gives rights to owner, usergroup and other
```